# mySQL - How can I query the multiple id, status pairs that indicate errors?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table with fields id, status, other_fields

It is fine to have multiple rows with the same id and status since they will have different other_fields.

But if some id has multiple (different) status values that indicates an error.

How can I write a query to return the id, status pairs that indicate an error? I have looked at the responses to related questions but, alas, I can't make the jump to my case.

Comment: RDB is a DBMS from Oracle (formerly from Digital), so I don't understand that tag together with your mentioning of MySQL

Comment: Aha ... RDB is to me just Relational Data Base ... I will be more careful.

Answer (score 0):

Try with something like this:

```
select t1.id, t1.status, t2.status
from table t1 
inner join table t2 on t1.id = t2.id
and t1.status != t2.status
order by t1.id
```

You can also `group_concat(t2.status)` and `group by t1.id` to get one row pr id..

Comment: Yup, just what I had put together. Keep it simple ... thank you for your time, I really do appreciate this community.